# Minecraft: Special Characters in Target Selector Arguments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm creating a system so when a player dies, an XPOrb is dropped at that location with a special name then the player can choose to teleport to that named XPOrb if they choose.

This system is already working, but I would like to improve it. Right now the name of that XPOrb is "bob" but I would like to make it something better like a face such as: (ಥ﹏ಥ)

And I'm able to spawn an entity with that custom name, but I'm not able to teleport to it using:

```
@e[name=(ಥ﹏ಥ)]
```

Because Minecraft recognizes some of the characters as invalid they way that I have entered them. I would greatly prefer having this face instead of text for the XPOrb, so it would be a big help if someone knew how to format this properly.

The following commands are the entire list of commands for my system:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount

/testfor @a[score_deaths_min=1]

/execute @a[score_deaths_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon XPOrb ~0 ~0 ~0 {CustomName:bob,CustomNameVisible:1}

/scoreboard players set @a[score_deaths_min=1] deaths 0
```

Now if the player chooses to teleport to that orb the command is:

```
/execute @e[name=bob] ~ ~ ~ /tp @p @e[name=bob]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put special characters in target selectors (it pretty much only supports names that players can have), but you can match them in NBT data.

`/scoreboard players tag` supports NBT data matching and adds a tag to an entity which can then be used in a selector. For example:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=XPOrb] add DeathOrb {CustomName:"(ಥ﹏ಥ)"}
```

Which means: "add a 'DeathOrb' scoreboard tag to any XPOrbs with a CustomName of (ಥ﹏ಥ)"

Then you can select it like:

```
/execute @e[tag=DeathOrb] ~ ~ ~ /tp @p @e[tag=DeathOrb]
```

---

If you're always going to be summoning in the orbs, then you could also summon it with the DeathOrb tag, like so:

```
/execute @a[score_deaths_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon XPOrb ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:(ಥ﹏ಥ),CustomNameVisible:1,Tags:[DeathOrb]}
```

Then select it with `@e[tag=DeathOrb]` as above.